# Using the same Assert method for multiple test cases?

Tags: c#, testing

I want to reuse a test method with other test cases, as they share the same functionality, but using different parameters. In the code below, `annualSalary`, `periodPortion` will be will be different. 
My question, is there a way to reuse the entire code block below for other test cases to avoid repeated code in other test methods?

```
       int actualTaxResult = IncomeTax.GetIncomeTax(annualSalary, _periodPortion);
        //int expectedTaxAmount = 922; 
       if (actualTaxResult != expectedTaxAmount)
       {
        Assert.Fail(String.Format("Expected tax amount: {0}, but actual result is {1}", expectedTaxAmount, actualTaxResult));
       }
```

Comment: _is there a way to reuse the entire code block below_ - how about creating a new method with the required parameters?

Comment: It seems like each Assert.Fail(..) belongs to each Test Method.

Comment: What unit testing framework are you using? If using NUnit, check out `[TestCaseAttribute]`.

Comment: sorry @everyone, I know what I need to do now, I was too sleepy to think through earlier..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things worth mentioning:

1. Certainly, this is normal to use parameterised tests
2. The best way to do this is to use proper testing framework, which natively supports parameterised tests (xUnit.Net, NUnit)

For example, with xUnit you can do:

```
[Theory]
[InlineData(100000, 10, 10000)]
[InlineData(150000, 15, 12000)]
[InlineData(210000, 2, 2450)]
public void IncomeTax_Specs(int annualSalary, int periodPortion, int expectedTaxAmount)
{
    int actualTaxResult = IncomeTax.GetIncomeTax(annualSalary, periodPortion);

    Assert.Equal(actualTaxResult, expectedTaxAmount);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you wrap that code block in a separate helper method and use it for different test cases like below. But you can change the method signature per need but the point to convey is *use a helper method*

```
private bool CheckData(int annualSalary, int _periodPortion, int expectedTaxAmount)
{
       int actualTaxResult = IncomeTax.GetIncomeTax(annualSalary, _periodPortion);
       return (actualTaxResult == expectedTaxAmount)
}
```

Then in your test method you can just say

```
   if (!CheckData(40000,6,300))
   {
    Assert.Fail(String.Format("Expected tax amount: {0}, but actual result is {1}", expectedTaxAmount, actualTaxResult));
   }
```

---

Initial answer helper method Per your comment

```
private void CheckData(int annualSalary, int _periodPortion, int expectedTaxAmount)
{
   int actualTaxResult = IncomeTax.GetIncomeTax(annualSalary, _periodPortion);
   if (actualTaxResult != expectedTaxAmount)
   {
    Assert.Fail(String.Format("Expected tax amount: {0}, but actual result is {1}", expectedTaxAmount, actualTaxResult));
   }
}
```

Comment: thanks, could you change to initial helper method that contains everything, that works.

Comment: @grepLines, see edit in answer if that helps

Comment: no I mean your initial answer was correct, if you could change it back to have just one method that contains Assert and wrap it outside a helper method, then I can mark them as accepted answer

Comment: @grepLines, that's what, have edited the answer and included the initial helper method code as well. But wanted to keep the other version as well since that could be helpful for others in future .. if not for you ... hope you understand

Comment: cool, thanks heaps :)